# Want to strip "@email.com" from input when users mistakenly include full email address as username

Tags: javascript

My company has a login page and we get numerous support calls from customers because they think their username is their full email address (user_id@email.com). The username is actually the first part of the email address before the @ symbol.

I'm not sure where to start. I inherited the login page responsibilities and am trying to make improvements but I'm a novice programmer.

Can I implement something like this?

```
user_id.split("@")[0]
```

Expected results would be if a user types "user_id@email.com" in the username field, when they click submit only "user_id" gets submitted.

Comment: Why wouldn't `user_id.split("@")[0]` work?

Comment: Why not just warn them with a message saying you're specifically asking for a username and not their email? Also, what are the guarantees that the username portion of their email is actually their account username? I could have a username `john` but my email could be `john.doe@dingbat.foo`.

Comment: Just silently remove the @... part on the server (for a better user experience).

Comment: If there is `@` character in the string, then throw an error to the user.

Comment: you can also check that the "email.com" is the one of your company before removing it.

Comment: @VLAZ I was thinking it would but I have no idea how to implement it. I'm in the early learning stages right now.

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately we don't control the authentication-side, only the client-side.

Comment: @Joseph the username is always the first part of the email address in our company. New users just don't know that because in other systems in the org they can use their email address or username interchangeably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VLAZ is right.

```js
let user_id = "foo@email.com";
user_id = user_id.split("@")[0];
console.log(user_id);
```

Will do the trick.

It's a good idea to open up the browser console and experiment before getting too caught up in your question. It's a quick and easy way to answer your own questions (F12 on desktops or right click > inspect element > Console on Chrome or Firefox).

**Edited after comment below:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="cleanUsername()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function cleanUsername() {
  let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (username.includes('@')) {
    username = username.split('@')[0];
  }
  alert(username); // To display results. This wouldn't really be in the code.
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @swhitmore. Would I use onClick or onSubmit or something like that to trigger this when the "login" button is clicked? How do you recommend implementing this on the page.

Comment: @Daniel it really depends on how the submission is being handled. Is this an just a plain html or php page with javascript or is it part of some framework like Reactjs or Angular? Are you using jQuery or just plain javascript? Assuming you're using plain javascript on a regular page you could wrap the split into a function like Matthew suggested and use the html "onsubmit" property to call it before submission.

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer to reflect what I was talking about in my last comment.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I have another question. My boss doesn't want the browser to offer to save the username/password with the '@email.com' part of the username. The code still strips it like it should even if the username is saved with the '@email.com' portion but do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: That could be browser specific and might require a little bit of experimentation on your part. My guess would be it would offer to save the username after being stripped because it's happening as a result of that "onsubmit" property.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two possible approaches to this**

1. Can do something like this on the frontend in the form

```
var user_id ="user@email.com";
user_id = user_id.split("@")[0];
```

2. or you can implement something during the form validation on the server.

The specific code for that depends on your stack. However, the server option is probably more reliable as then you can also check that the email corresponds to the correct client domain or even could look up the username with the email and log them in that way.

**Updated Version based on OP Feedback about Implementation**

```
<input id="username" type="text" onblur="stripUsername()">
<button type="button">Submit</button>

<script>
function stripUsername() {
  document.getElementById("username").value = document.getElementById("username").value.split("@")[0];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Matthew. I do like the simplicity. I just have no clue how to implement this on the page. When I run that in the console it outputs "user" like it should but how to I tell the form output what the user has typed in the username field.

Comment: @Daniel try something like the above. I edited my answer to account for your question.